# Github Action - receive event when comment added to PR?

Tags: github-actions

Is there a way to get a Github Action to trigger on a PR when a comment is added to that PR?  I've created a Github action that will trigger on a variety of events that occur on PRs (created, etc).  The one piece I haven't figured out is the trigger for when a comment is added.  I'm not seeing anything here that would indicate it's supported:

https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitHub pull requests are actually issues. So the event you are looking for is [`issue_comment`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#issue-comment-event-issue_comment).

```
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]
```

You can filter out just pull request comment events like this:

```
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]
jobs:
  example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Execute for pull request comments only
        if: github.event.issue.pull_request
        run: echo "This is a pull request comment event"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me - here's a PR (on the repo containing my GH action) that doesn't seem to trigger on issue_comment.  It triggers when I add a commit to PR, but not for comments...

https://github.com/delivered/trello-github-action/pull/1

Comment: The workflow must be committed to the master branch for `issue_comment` events to trigger. See the documentation where it says the `GITHUB_SHA` for the event is the “last commit on default branch.”

Comment: So does the comment itself have to be on the master branch?  Here's what I've got:

* .github/workflows/main.yml on default (master) branch registering the issue_comment event
* create new branch, workflow triggers when I create PR.
* workflow does NOT trigger when I add comments to this PR/branch

I'd like this workflow to enforce rules against a PR, but if it will only respond to issue_comment on the master branch, I'm not sure I can accomplish that?  Apologies if I"m missing something obvious :(

Comment: The comment can be in any issue or pull request. When a comment is made an event is created. GitHub will then check the last commit of your default branch (master) to see if there is an `issue_comment` event workflow. If there is, it executes it. Workflows in other branches are not considered for the `issue_comment` event.

Comment: I'm not sure what your use case is, but if you are trying to use slash commands to execute a workflow against a PR, [slash-command-dispatch](https://github.com/peter-evans/slash-command-dispatch) action may help you.

Comment: is there a way to trigger this event only if the comment is equal to "retest" and it should not trigger if any other comment is posted?

Comment: for reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#issue_comment

Comment: this does not seem to work when the PR creator adds a comment upon PR opening

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to run a workflow when an "issue_comment" (can be an issue or PR) is created that also contains the text "run workflow")

```yaml
name: Run Workflow on PR Comment
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]
  
jobs:
  rerun-tests-job:
    if: contains(github.event.comment.body, 'run workflow')
    uses: ./.github/workflows/main.yml
```